# JPA @One-To-Many mapping on composite key

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I have these 2 entities `EmailTemplate` and `EmailText`, where one `EmailTemplate` instance can have multiple `EmailText` instances (One-to-Many relationship).

- `EmailTemplate` is supposed to contain the core information of the
  email template
- `EmailText` is the place to keep the contents of the
  email template in different languages
- `emailId` is a generated unique identifier for `EmailTemplate`, and also part of the composite key for `EmailText` along with `lang`

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class EmailTemplate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long emailId;

    private String emailCode;

    private Integer version;

    private Boolean isHtml;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "emailTemplate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EmailText> emailText;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Embeddable
@IdClass(EmailTextPK.class) //A composite key which contains emailId & lang
public class EmailText implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emailId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private EmailTemplate emailTemplate;

    @Id
    private Long emailId;

    @Id
    private String lang;

    //used if isHtml is false
    private String text;

    private String subject;

    //used if isHtml is true
    private String template;
}
```

After I got the service up and running, I have a request to add one `EmailTemplate` and a few `EmailText` that goes with it. The flow should be:

1. Add new `EmailTemplate` record into the repository
2. Automatically add a generated ID for `EmailTemplate`'s `emailId` field
3. Cascade this new `emailId` for all `EmailText` records that belonged to this template

> **EDIT (2021-05-20):**
> This is the DTO I'm using to accept the payload for add:
>
> ```java
> @Data
> public class EmailTemplateDto {
>     private String emailCode;
>
>     private Integer version;
>
>     private Boolean isHtml;
>
>     private List<EmailTextDto> text;
> }
>
> @Data
> public class EmailTextDto {
>     private String lang;
>
>     private String text;
>
>     private String subject;
>
>     private String template;
> }
> ```
>
> A sample payload would look like this:
>
> ```json
> {
>    "emailCode": "VERIFY_REGISTRATION",
>    "version": 1,
>    "isHtml": false,
>    "text": [
>        {
>            "lang": "en-US",
>            "text": "<link to verification>",
>            "subject": "Verify Your Registration",
>            "template": ""
>        },
>        {
>            "lang": "ja-JP",
>            "text": "<link to verification>",
>            "subject": "Verify Your Registration (assume it's translated)",
>            "template": ""
>        }
>    ]
> }
> ```
>
> After the service received the request with this payload, this DTO is mapped to the EmailTemplate class, then a persist method is called to save it into the EmailTemplateRepository.
>
> No explicit persist method is called for EmailText(s).

Right now I'm having this error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "email_id" of relation "email_text" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, en-US, EN Test Email, <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head></html>, Text of EN Test Email).
```

My current understanding of the problem is that when the `EmailTemplate` record is inserted, Step 1 & 2 of the flow are working just fine, the ID is automatically added for the record.

But at the same time the `EmailText` records are inserted, and they do not have the generated ID, that's what's violating the not-null constraint for `emailID`. (My guess is potentially, Step 3 is happening before Step 2)

Comment: how do you create new EmailTexts? do you set EmailText.emailId when you create new EmailText?

Comment: @tremendous7 No, I don't set the EmailText.emailId in this scenario, because it is a FK from EmailTemplate... I've added some details to the question, please have a look & see whether it clarifies the question

Comment: the emailId in EmailText has to be manually set because it is not mapped. save your EmailTemplate with a call and save the new EmailText(s) with another one after manually setting the emailId taken from the freshly persisted EmailTemplate

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing at the moment without the relationship annotations

Comment: With the annotations, I'm only calling the method to persist the EmailTemplate, then the EmailText(s) will be persisted as well since they're the children of this EmailTemplate, but this is where I'm facing the issue